# Next.js / React - load one script before the other

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have the following in the Head of a page to load two scripts:

```
  <Head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/myscript.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </Head>
```

I want the loading order of the scripts to be strict, since `myscript.min.js` uses jQuery.

What I'm obtaining though is that the first time I load the page, jQuery is still not loaded when `myscript.min.js` executes, since jQuery is much bigger. So what I get is that jQuery is undefined.

How can I force jQuery to load first?

Comment: Use [`next/script`](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/script). Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-field-l3loc -- jQuery is loading before my script.

Comment: I've looked into it, but unfortunately it's only available on Next.js v11. I can only use v9 due to platform restrictions.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `defer` attribute to the script. Scripts with the defer attribute will execute in the order in which they appear in the document.

```
 <Head>
    <script defer src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/static/js/myscript.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </Head>
```

[MDN link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer)

Comment: Same problem, no luck with defer